# How to display nearby ATMs based on my current location using Google maps in Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

How to display nearby ATMs based on my current location using Google maps in Javascript/JQuery?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Script

```
var map;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(11.2333, 78.1667);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: pyrmont,
    zoom: 15
  });

  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: 5500,
    types: ['atm']
  };
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p78WT/1/)

Comment: can u please suggest how to pass the latitude and longitude obtained by geolocator instead of hard coding?

Comment: i updated this fiddle check http://jsfiddle.net/p78WT/2/

Comment: thnx thnx a lot!!!! Cheers!!!!!

Comment: Hmm, how come this works without API key? Nearbysearch is a paid service https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage-and-billing#nearby-search

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a [working example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search) from Google Maps API v3 Docs

The example uses store, replace with 'atm' ;)

EDIT: If you need another Place Type here is the [full list](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types)